# Identifying the father of a man born in Lemberg/Lviv/Lwow in 1884/85?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, austria, parentage

My great grandfather, Ignacy Isadore Pfeffer, was born in Lemberg, Austria in 1884/1885.

We know that this area has traded hands multiple times in the years since his birth and was also known as Lviv/Lwow.

From searches in several places (including Ancestry, jewishGen and jri-poland) we have a name for his mother: Fajga Pfeffer. However, no father was listed in the birth record.

Fajga Pfeffer had multiple children, and most did not have a father listed. Her last two children did have a father listed, but he was not the one listed on my great grandfather's tombstone (Yakov Shmuel-- no last name given).

So we are looking to get a confirmation of the father and a last name for him. What steps should we take next?

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting and make the information you have and the information you need more clear. Please re-edit it yourself if I've introduced any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching Gesher Galicia? Its free All Galicia Database has hundreds of thousands of records, including thousands of records from Lviv:
http://search.geshergalicia.org

Was Ignacy's mother Fajga Pfeffer also born in Lviv? If so, it looks like her 1850 birth record is included in the database.

And there are several people named "Jakob Samuel" listed as being born in Lviv in the 1830-1865 time period in that database. One possibility is Jakob Samuel (no last name in the birth record, which was typical), son of Abraham Iser REIS & Dreze BARDACH, born in Lviv in 1860.

Comment: We did try Gesher Galicia and didn't get satisfactory results. We are unsure that Fajga is Ignacy's mother (there is only her name on the birth records in jrl-poland and she had a number of kids without fathers not listed. The Jacob Samuels listed in jri-poland did not have a son named Ignacy in records we searched. so we are kind of at a stuck point there.

Comment: It looks like a scanned image of your great-grandfather's birth certificate should be available at AGAD's website, here...

http://agadd.home.net.pl/metrykalia/300/sygn.%20550/indeks.htm

...but the link for that entire book, #550, is giving a 404.  According to JRI's index, he would be record # 504 in book #550.  You may want to write to AGAD directly, ask them about the missing book, and ask for a copy of the image.